# DataTables won't run render function after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I'm using AJAX to get data into my Datatables table. This is something I've done before and it worked fine, but this time I'm running into an issue.

When I run `InitializeDatatables` JS function, it successfully generates the table and runs the AJAX which reaches the `GetDataForTable` controller action. However, nothing more happens once the controller action returns. What should happen is the function in `"render"` section should run but it does not. No error is given either.

As far as I can tell, this setup is very similar to one I had in another project, but I can't find where I'm making a mistake. One difference is that the previous project was on ASP.NET Core 3.0 and this one is on 2.2.

HTML table setup:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>
                  Important Stuff
             </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
//Datatables automatically generates the rest of HTML needed
</table>
```

JS function that runs on page load:

```
function InitializeDatatables() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "lengthChange": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Home/GetDataForTable", //controller action runs and returns
            "type": "GET",
            error: function (error) {
                var test = error; //no error is given
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": null } //"data: null" to access all JSON data in "render" function(data).
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": 0,
                "render": function (data) { //function never runs
                    var test = data;
                    return '<span>test</span>';
                }
            },
            {"className": "testClass", "targets": 0} //class name is successfully added
        ]
    });
}
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetDataForTable()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    model.ImportantStuff = _myProcessingService.GetDataFromDB();
    return Json(new { data = model });
}
```

Comment: Is there any error showing in browser console?

Comment: No, there's nothing that shows up.

Comment: Can you try to test in [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/95xuek0t/). Is data showing in UI like this?

Comment: I don't exactly understand how to implement this into my own structure. But the ways I tried did not make it work.

Comment: So, in this project `model.ImportantStuff` was a dictionary but in the other project it was a list. Converting it to a list fixed the issue. Based on my research, it looks like Datatables can only handle JSON arrays or objects as its data source. Am I correct?